# Newsletter Design to send in emails, using tables or table less

Tags: html, css

How HTML newsletters should be designed? using tables or divs and css styles.

I read somewhere that newsletter should be designed using tables because many of the old client can't process the css style. how much truth is in this?

What else need to be care of when designing newsletter to send using email.

i.e. java script should not be used in newsletter as it is disabled in most of the email clients. what else?

I have read this article. although it was written two years back but I am not sure If writen things are still valid...
http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/code-html-email-newsletters

Comment: You can't use PHP in a newsletter; removed that tag.

Comment: HTML newsletters are best avoided IMO. The work required to write HTML that works in a majority of desktop and webmail clients is wide-ranging, challenges all modern good practice, and is IMO typically just not worth it. Unless you really want to waste days of your life testing and uglifying your markup, just go with a text mail containing a link to a normal web page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a good place to start: 
http://www.campaignmonitor.com/design-guidelines/

Or in general:
http://www.campaignmonitor.com/resources/category-archive/cat/designing-and-building-emails/

PS: I've no relation with the site but I do think the articles are really useful though some are dated a few years ago.

Answer (score 3):

Tables are usually the best option for consistent layout in HTML emails - some email clients have problems with `div`s.

CSS usually has to be inline (ie on each item to be styled) or embedded in the page - embedded CSS can't be in the `<head>` section (since this may be stripped out by web-based clients).

Here's a couple of links from MailChimp about designing HTML emails which I've found useful:

http://www.mailchimp.com/blog/background-images-and-css-in-html-email/
 http://www.mailchimp.com/kb/article/how-to-code-html-emails/

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the version of Outlook the user has, background images will not work (2007) due to security concerns, but they will work in 2003.

When I created an email campaign for a company I worked for, we broke the newsletter into sections of images that linked to various areas of our site using a table to structure it with some css. Worked for most email clients.

Answer (score 0):

As it is News letter, it does not need be SEO. Better to have table instead of DIV. and Table render faster than Div.

Answer (score 0):

I did some research into this for a client about a year ago based on analytics from sending 200,000 newsletters.

I did lots of mail client testing and discovered (very sadly) that the most reliable coding method was sticking to the W3C HTML 3 standard.

Problem is a frightening number of people are still using Outlook 2000 and some really old versions of outlook express.